# Android: Starting Alarm Service from Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-alarms, android-intentservice

I'm trying to start a 1 minute alarm from a dialog box. This is my dialog method (with AlarmManager and everything):

```
    public void Dialog2(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Email!")
            .setMessage("Would You Like to Set a 1 Minute Reminder?\nRemember to Email Your Professor!")
            .setPositiveButton("Set Alarm!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

                    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                                    60 * 1000, alarmIntent);


                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

This is my AlarmReceiver Class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Don't Forget To Email Your Teacher!.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
}
}
```

In my AndroidManifest, I've included:

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ServiceClass" />
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

This is my Service Class:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class ServiceClass extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

}
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you add set_alarm permission in menifest?

Comment: What's your question?  Are you saying its not working?  If so, what isn't working?  Are you not getting an alarm?  Something in the alarm not happening?  Something else?  I'm also not sure why you posted some of this code-  your service does nothing and isn't involved or needed from what you posted.

Comment: What issue you are getting..is Alarm not started..or any error, share your logcat if any error..

Comment: @DivyeshPatel No permission is needed to use AlarmManager.

Comment: Instead of `alarmMgr.set(` this, try to use `alarmMgr.setExact(`.

Comment: I think this is needed for Alarm :  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

Comment: My alarm just isn't working. I'll wait the set amount of time and it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code based on [Android Dev Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set) is working, to be more precise, this one:

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

Alarm.Receiver.java:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

            /* class1 = new MainActivity();
            class1.message();*/
        Toast.makeText(context, "Don't Forget To Email Your Teacher!.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null)
        {
            alarmUri =       RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

    }
}
```

3 things I needed to do to make it work (on API 16 to 25):

Add permissions BEFORE application in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Move receiver WITHIN application:

```
<receiver android:name=".Action.AlarmReceiver"> //change according to your path
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And finally ... reboot Android Studio.
Yep, I don't know why, but I had to do it to make it work in my case.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a service from AlarmManager you should start the service in onReceive method of AlarmReceiver class